# How to make bin for the each row of dataframe only with the non NA values?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, apply

I have a dataframe which contains values and NAs. Some of them have the NAs from the start of the row, some of them have the NAs at the end of the row.

```
# like this way
df<- data.frame(A=c(1,5,6,   1,NA,NA),
                  B=c(1,2,3,   2,NA,NA),
                  C=c(1,3,NA,  4,3,NA),
                  D=c(1,1,NA,  6,10,NA),
                  E=c(1,NA,NA, 1,1,1),
                  F=c(1,NA,NA, 1,1,1))
```

Now I would like to build two bins for each row based on the non NA values and sum them up.

```
#expected output
Sum   Bin
3     1
3     2
7     1
5     2
6     1
3     2
...
```

Now what I did is I first separate the dataframe into 2 base on whether the row will start or end with NAs. Then I use a loop for the calculation.

```
df_bin <- data.frame(Sum = 0, Bin = 0)

bin  = 2 # set bin for the calculation
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  l <- sum(!is.na(df[i,]))
  ll <- as.integer(l/bin)
  s <- c()
  j <- 1
  while (j <= (bin-1)) {
    k <- sum(df[i,(j*ll-ll+1):(j*ll)])
    s <- c(s,k) 
    j = j+1
  }
  k <- k <- sum(df[i,(j*(bin-1)+1):l])
  s <- c(s,k) 
  df2 <- data.frame(Sum = s, Bin = 1:bin)
  df_bin <- rbind(df_bin,df2)
}
```

But it runs very slow, I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do it. Thank you in advance : )

Comment: I'm confused at how you are calculating your desired output... can you explain how the calculation for `Sum` and `Bin` are done (rowwise) ?

Comment: @Wimpel Yes it is, I calculate the sum of columns in the Bin for each row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure `tidyverse` solution using pivoting:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(orig_row = 1:n()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-orig_row) %>% filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
  group_by(orig_row) %>% mutate(Bin = round(1 + seq(0, n() - 1) / n())) %>%
  group_by(orig_row, Bin) %>% summarise(Sum = sum(value)) %>% ungroup() %>%
  select(-orig_row)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 2
     Bin   Sum
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     3
 2     2     3
 3     1     7
 4     2     4
 5     1     6
 6     2     3
 7     1     7
 8     2     8
 9     1    13
10     2     2
11     1     1
12     2     1
```

Comment: Hi again, I was wondering if I would like to sum the value by using 100 bins.  Now I use %>% mutate(Bin = round(1 + seq(0, n() - 1) / n()*99)). But it makes some rows lost the last bin (bin 100). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really think about how to generalise to more bins before. In this case I would do `mutate(Bin = ceiling(2 * seq_along(value) / n()))`, where you replace `2` with the number of bins you need. Let me know if this works for you

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `apply` :

```
do.call(rbind, apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  #Remove NA values
  x1 <- na.omit(x)
  #Calculate length of non-NA values
  n <- length(x1)
  #Calculate mid point
  half_len <- round(n/2)
  #Create dataframe with sum of two bin values
  data.frame(Sum = c(sum(x1[1:half_len]), sum(x1[(half_len + 1):n])), 
             Bin = 1:2)
}))

#   Sum Bin
#1    3   1
#2    3   2
#3    7   1
#4    4   2
#5    6   1
#6    3   2
#7    7   1
#8    8   2
#9   13   1
#10   2   2
#11   1   1
#12   1   2
```